# rospack could not find the controller_interface package containing controller_interface::ControllerBase

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to run gazebo simulator with my package and this error thrown.

```
[FATAL] [1386622156.026160179, 0.419000000]: Failed to create robot simulation interface loader: rospack could not find the controller_interface package containing controller_interface::ControllerBase
```

the simulation is successfully started, but the controllers are down, so the robot cannot be controlled.

when i try to locate the controller_interface package it exists:

```
omrib@ubuntu:~$ rospack find controller_interface
/opt/ros/hydro/share/controller_interface
omrib@ubuntu:~$ cd /opt/ros/hydro/share/controller_interface
omrib@ubuntu:/opt/ros/hydro/share/controller_interface$ ls
cmake  package.xml
```

any idea?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/108626/rospack-could-not-find-the-controller_interface-package-containing-controller_interface::controllerbase/) by [omrib](https://answers.ros.org/users/9731/omrib/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-12-09

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arn-O](https://answers.ros.org/users/5387/arn-o/) on 2013-12-12**:
Hi. Same issue here. (posted on the Gazebo side: http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5099/rospack-could-not-find-the-controller_interface/). It looks like the package is broken on the repo, since it is ... empty.

**Comment by [comrob_commander](https://answers.ros.org/users/9906/comrob_commander/) on 2013-12-14**:
I can confirm this, how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

this helped for me:
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-ros-controllers

---

Originally posted by [comrob_commander](https://answers.ros.org/users/9906/comrob_commander/) with karma: 56 on 2013-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [omrib](https://answers.ros.org/users/9731/omrib/) on 2013-12-14**:
tnx Comrob it works!!

**Comment by [dmeltz](https://answers.ros.org/users/2498/dmeltz/) on 2013-12-28**:
works for me also ! thanks a lot !